# How to find wwn through EFI Shell?

Tags: uefi, hba

I have not installed any OS in the server. HBA card is attached to the server and after power ON it enters into EFI shell. I entered below command and it show FC driver

```
drivers
```

Output like

```
17F 00000629 D N Y  2 0 HP Fibre Channel Driver PcieRoot(0x1)/Pci....
```

After that I give driver config but with no success,

```
drvcfg -s 17F
```

How do I get wwn through EFI Shell?

Comment: Humm, typically you need to provide 2 numbersm i.e. drvcfg -s 17 21, not just one number

Comment: why do I need to use 2nd number? what that will be denote to?